# How to test a directory path that matches a specific pattern/regex?

Tags: c#, regex, nunit

I have the following test which aims to ensure that file path generated is of a specific format. Using Nunit's fluent interfaces, how can I go about this?

I am having trouble with the regex.

```
  [Test]
    public void AssetControlPath_ShouldHaveFormat_BaseDir_YYYY_MMM_YYYYMMMDD() 
    {
        //Arrange
        var baseDir = "C:\\BaseDir";
        var fpBuilder = new FilePathBuilder(new DateTime(2010,10,10), baseDir );

        //Act
        var destinationPath = fpBuilder.AssetControlPath();

        //Assert
        // destinationPath = C:\BasDir\2010\Oct\20101010
    Assert.That(destinationPath, Is.StringMatching(@"C:\\BaseDir\\d{4}\\[a-zA-Z]{3}\\d{8}"));              
    }
```

The unit test error
`XXX.FilepathBuilderTests.AssetControlPath_ShouldHaveFormat_BaseDir_YYYY_MMM_YYYYMMMDD:
Expected: String matching "C:\\BaseDir\\d{4}\\[a-zA-Z]{3}\\d{8}"
But was:  "C:\BaseDir\2010\Oct\20101010"`

**Edit:**
I have actually switched the test to use @ChrisF's approach. The question however still stands.

Comment: BTW, if you use the @ symbol for a string literal, you don't need to escape the backslash, so  @"C:\BaseDir\d{4}\\[a-zA-Z]{3}]\d{8}" might be what you need.

Comment: @SWeko - it's in the comment above the test. I missed it at first too.

Comment: @sweko - tried that and a few other combinations. Does not work. The error is the as posted except the `String Matching` part has one less `\\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@"C:\\BaseDir\\d{4}\\[a-zA-Z]{3}]\\d{8}"
//                              /\ extra bracket
```

Also you have a problem with `\` escaping, you need `\\\d{4}` and `\\\d{8}`, you want to match `xxx\20101010` and not `xxx20101010`. The following fix matches correct:

```
var str = @"C:\BaseDir\2010\Oct\20101010";
var re = new Regex(@"C:\\BaseDir\\\d{4}\\[a-zA-Z]{3}\\\d{8}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var result = re.IsMatch(str); // true
```

Comment: +1 awesome. i will stick with ChrisF approach to this test for the reasons he mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

A `String.Split` with `\` as the split character and then check that you get the right number of elements (5) and that each element is the expected value might be:

a) be clearer in what the intent of the test is and

b) easier to maintain.

Comment: or use named groups in the Regex and test on those.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra closing square bracket!! remove that and it chould be fine.